# Difference in precision in np.float64 and python float (64)

Tags: python, numpy, printing, precision

Why does (or seems that) the python float has more precision than `numpy.float64`. Here I leave an example:

```
import numpy as np

ann = 72.595895691
detections = np.array([0, 71.91000009999999], dtype=np.float64)
group_det = [1]
dist1 = [ann - detections[det] for det in group_det]
dist = np.zeros(len(group_det), dtype=np.float64)
for idx, det in enumerate(group_det):
    dist[idx] = ann - detections[det]
print(f'dist1: {dist1}')
print(f'dist {dist}')
```

The output of this code is:

```
dist1: [0.6858955910000049]
dist [0.68589559]
```

My questions is why **dist1** has more precision?

*Note: The code seems like is doing things in a very complicated way, but I had to cut a little portion of my code with the same behaviour.*

Comment: that's a display diffeeence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @hpaulj in comments, it is not calculation precision. It is printing. Add this line to your code to see the precision you would like while printing in numpy:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=16)
```

output of your code after above line:

```
dist1: [0.6858955910000049]
dist [0.6858955910000049]
```